# Angular animation with plugged sounds/audio when animation trigger is being called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I am looking for a solution to play audio each time the Angular animation trigger is called. I have an animation with 8 elements (8 triggers) with different duration and delays.

I was trying to implement audio.play() method each time animation has started but it's not working properly at all.

`(@trigger.start)="playAudio($event)"`

```
    playAudio(event: any) {
    if (event['fromState'] !== 'void') {
        let audio = new Audio('../../assets/audio/click1.wav');
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help!